# How do I prevent this: I switch focus to a different app (alt+tab), switch back to Pycharm, then Project tree collapses?

Tags: pycharm

Is there a setting I can change to prevent that? Otherwise, to get rid of it, I have to uninstall/reinstall!

It's annoying because I need to navigate through the Project tree again to get to the script/file that I was working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use "Project Files" instead of "Projects" but right now it doesn't seemed to be fixed although JetBrains has fixed this bug for IntelliJ

Comment: Shoot - that's a shame! This bug makes it really tough to use PyCharm as productively as possible. Thanks for the suggestion!